# How to use php variable in mysql for result

Tags: php

```
$min_range=$_GET['min_range'];
$max_range=$_GET['max_range'];
$brand_name=$_GET['brand'];

$result=mysql_query(
    "
        SELECT 
            brand,
            image,
            price
        FROM 
            mobile
        WHERE 
            brand = '"$brand_name " 'price =3000
    "
);
```

I want to use php variable in my sql query . What is wrong with this code. and how it can be corrected.

it is saying "parse error:syntax error,unexpect('$brand_name')"

Comment: Just as an additional point: the `mysql` driver is deprecated. You should read up on MySQLi or PDO. Also, it will be a good idea to read up on prepared statements.

Comment: SQL injections detected. Also, read more PHP tutorials like http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: it is called concatenation, but still your query has an invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

One way is the following:

```
$result=mysql_query(
    "
        SELECT 
            brand,
            image,
            price
        FROM 
            mobile
        WHERE 
            brand = '" . $brand_name . "'
        AND
            price =3000
    "
);
```

another way is this:

```
$result=mysql_query(
    "
        SELECT 
            brand,
            image,
            price
        FROM 
            mobile
        WHERE 
            brand = '$brand_name'
        AND
            price = 3000
    "
);
```

Another way is this:

```
$result=mysql_query(
    sprintf(
        "
            SELECT 
                brand,
                image,
                price
            FROM 
                mobile
            WHERE 
                brand = '%s'
            AND
                price = 3000
        ",
        $brand_name
    )
);
```

Also notice that your code, comes with syntax errors, replace the AND operator with one that meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT brand,image,price FROM mobile WHERE brand='$brand_name' AND price=3000");
```

You actually forgot to separate the condition. Added an **`AND`** keyword.

Comment: OHOO.. I am what a noob :( .. thaank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT brand,image,price FROM mobile WHERE brand = '$brand_name' AND price = 3000");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query(
    "
        SELECT 
            brand,
            image,
            price
        FROM 
            mobile
        WHERE 
            brand = '.$brand_name.' AND price =3000
    "
);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
    $result=mysql_query(
    "
        SELECT brand, image, price
        FROM mobile
        WHERE 
            brand = '" . $brand_name . "' AND price = 3000
     ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$result = $mysql->prepare("SELECT brand, image, price FROM mobile WHERE brand =? AND price=3000");`

`$result->bind_param($brand_name);`

`$result->execute();`